# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument' what(): stoi (Can't find what is wrong)

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    int calPoints(vector<string>& ops) {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < ops.size(); i++){
            if(ops[i] != "C" && ops[i] !=  "D" && ops[i] != "+"){
                sum += stoi(ops[i]);
            }
            else if(ops[i] == "C"){
                ops.erase(ops.begin() + (i-1));
                ops.erase(ops.begin() + (i-1));
                i = i-2;
            }
            else if(ops[i] == "D"){
                sum += (stoi(ops[i-1]) * 2);
                ops.erase(ops.begin() + i);
                i = i-1;
            }
            else{
                sum += (stoi(ops[i-1]) + stoi(ops[i-2]));
                ops.erase(ops.begin() + i);
                i = i-1;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

I looked up what the error message meant and others stated that I was feeding the argument 'bad information.' However, I personally can not find what is wrong with my code. Could anyone please assist me? Here is the goal:

```
You're now a baseball game point recorder.

Given a list of strings, each string can be one of the 4 following types:

Integer (one round's score): Directly represents the number of points you get in this round.
"+" (one round's score): Represents that the points you get in this round are the sum of the last two valid round's points.
"D" (one round's score): Represents that the points you get in this round are the doubled data of the last valid round's points.
"C" (an operation, which isn't a round's score): Represents the last valid round's points you get were invalid and should be removed.
Each round's operation is permanent and could have an impact on the round before and the round after.

You need to return the sum of the points you could get in all the rounds.

Input: ["5","2","C","D","+"]
Output: 30
Explanation: 
Round 1: You could get 5 points. The sum is: 5.
Round 2: You could get 2 points. The sum is: 7.
Operation 1: The round 2's data was invalid. The sum is: 5.  
Round 3: You could get 10 points (the round 2's data has been removed). The sum is: 15.
Round 4: You could get 5 + 10 = 15 points. The sum is: 30.
```

This is a LeetCode problem, not homework!

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: In `sum += (stoi(ops[i-1]) * 2);` and `sum += (stoi(ops[i-1]) + stoi(ops[i-2]));` you need to make sure `ops[...]` is a valid integer.

Comment: It's not related to the error, but when you process `C` you need to subtract the last round from `sum`.

Comment: [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) throws a `std::invalid_argument` exception if the input `std::string` can't be converted to an `int`. You are not catching that exception, which ultimately leads the app to terminate itself. Also, what does the content of `ops` look like? The loop is `erase()`'ing elements from `ops`, so there is a risk that `i` is going out of range. Any time you need a loop that removes elements from the container being looped through, a `for` loop is a bad choice to use.

Comment: @NathanOliver From my analysis I believe I do not need to check whether the stoi is a valid integer or not because I know for sure the first variable can not or at least should not be according to the instructions a non integer value. Therefore, any other following string should be able to be converted regardless because I am removing the characters that I do not need. For example, for the input above, when I get to C, I remove C, so when I get to D, I know for sure all I have is an integer value before. I make sure to remove and non-integer value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau What do you suggest I use instead of a for loop? I also thought it would be bad, but could not think of anything else. I couldn't think of a way to use a while loop because the size would not be able to change according to my method because I am not deleting all the values and therefore would not be able to make the conditional statement to be ">=0" etc... Thanks guys.

Comment: @PracticingCodeMan your whole code is wrong and needs to be re-written. You don't need to delete anything from the `ops` vector. I posted an answer to show that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Hey Remy, thank you for your help! I am trying to understand your code... I have not learned C++ 11 or beyond yet so it is quite troublesome! I did; however, solve the problem and have it posted on LeetCode. Here is the link: https://leetcode.com/problems/baseball-game/discuss/142911/C++-Solution-Please-Give-Feedback!

Answer (score 0):

`std::stoi()` throws a `std::invalid_argument` exception if the input `std::string` value cannot be converted to an `int`. You are not catching that exception.  If it escapes from `main()`, the app will terminate itself.

Also, your loop is `erase()`'ing elements from `ops`, so there is a risk that your `i` index can go out of range if you are not careful, especially since you are not performing any range checks.  And there are indeed logic errors in your case blocks where you are not managing `ops` and `i` correctly.

Any time you need a loop that removes elements from the container that is being looped through, a `for` loop is a bad choice to use.  A `while` loop is typically better, so that you have more control over the indexing.

However, your whole code is just plain wrong in general and needs to be re-written.  You are not following the instructions that you were given, as you are not calculating the points per round as instructed.  You are performing calculations strictly on the input values in `ops`, which is not what the instructions asked you to do.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <stdexcept>

class Solution {
public:
    int calPoints(const std::vector<std::string> &ops)
    {
        std::vector<int> rounds;
        int points;

        for(auto &op : ops)
        {
            if (op == "C")
            {
                if (rounds.empty())
                    throw std::out_of_range("Not enough valid rounds!");

                rounds.pop_back();
            }
            else if (op == "D")
            {
                if (rounds.empty())
                    throw std::out_of_range("Not enough valid rounds!");

                points = rounds.back() * 2;
                rounds.push_back(points);
            }
            else if (op == "+")
            {
                const std::vector<int>::size_type numRounds = rounds.size();
                if (numRounds < 2)
                    throw std::out_of_range("Not enough valid rounds!");

                points = rounds[numRounds-2] + rounds[numRounds-1];
                rounds.push_back(points);
            }
            else
            {
                points = std::stoi(op);
                rounds.push_back(points);
            }
        }

        return std::accumulate(rounds.begin(), rounds.end(), 0);
    }
};
```

This produces a sum of `30` from an input of `["5","2","C","D","+"]`, as expected.

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/9ZaNca)